# Can a site detect if I use AdBlock in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, privacy, adblock

I recently visited (an official) website in search for an episode of a TV-show. The site popped an information dialog stating that I had to disable AdBlock to see the content. Is this at all possible or is it just an educated guess? Does Firefox advertise what addons I have installed? If so: how and why does it work that way?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes, a website can detect that Adblock Plus is installed by referencing a Javascript file known to be blocked by Adblock Plus (because it matches a default rule) and check if this Javascript code has run, by checking a variable for instance.

See an explanation here: [**How To Detect Adblock Plus**](http://blog.taragana.com/index.php/archive/how-to-detect-adblock-plus/)

And more details at Wikipedia: [**Adblock - Detection**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adblock#Detection).

Answer (score 5):

It's entirely possible, it can be done with a bit of javascript. You can see a proof of concept [here](http://www.adblock.org/2004/07/adblock_detection_script/) that shows how to detect multiple different adblock programs, which also uses javascript for detection. It isn't really the fact that Firefox "advertises" your installed add-ons, it's the method that most adblock programs use to function. Most will simply [hide elements](http://adblockplus.org/en/faq_internal#elemhide) using the CSS visibility property and filter certain URLs. These URLs can be faked in an attempt to fool the filter, and it is an ongoing battle with regards to [blocking detection](http://adblockplus.org/development-builds/adblock-plus-detection-possibility-closed).

Comment: Also interesting answer. Will look at poc to get more information.

Comment: It seems to have been fixed. I clicked on the first link and the detecting script link was broken.

Answer (score 3):

Without using any trickery, most browsers advertise installed plugins (like Flash), but not add-ons (like Adblock, which is detectable by other means [like Snark answered](https://superuser.com/questions/104118/can-a-site-detect-if-i-use-adblock-in-firefox/104119#104119)). See [Panopticlick](https://panopticlick.eff.org/), and help their investigation...