# How to stop a browser to leak the list of installed add-ons/extensions?

Tags: browser, browser-addons

Usually the websites are able to see which add-ons or extensions are installed on my browser, how can I prevent the browser (Firefox or Chrome) to leak the list of installed add-ons or extensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a kinda yes and no question. Yes it is possible, But no they cannot see the specific addon if its not making use of any run times or user agents. For instance some ad blockers make use of javascript to detect ads and block them. If the site realizes the script doesn't run it can run a 'hey please stop ad-block'. But they cant tell on what specific add on is blocking. Only by looking at the way it acts.

Ofcourse using javascript for addons as of late is not used that often. But its just an example.

There are only 2 ways for a website to tell something about the users browser.

More information:
[Can websites see my Firefox Addons?](https://superuser.com/questions/137931/can-websites-see-my-firefox-addons)

Comment: They use JavaScript. [JavaScript is not Java](http://javascriptisnotjava.io/). Note that the link you quote has the correct information :)

Comment: @DavidPostill apologies good sir.